# Get id of FactoryBoy factory with LazyAttribute when using DjangoModelFactory

Tags: django, factory-boy

I have the following factory and want to access the id of an instance that will be created from it:

```
class PlatformFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    type = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(Platform.Type)
    name = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText(length=30)
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    ext = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda self: f"{self.user.key}|{self.id}")

    class Meta:
        model = Platform
        exclude = ["user", ]
```

Unfortunately it gives me the error `AttributeError: The parameter 'id' is unknown. Evaluated attributes are {'type': <Type.OTHER: 2>, 'name': ...`

But since it is a django model there is an id present. Why is this not recognized by factory boy and how can I solve this?

Thanks and regards
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs on [LazyAttribute](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#lazyattribute), the method accepts the object being built, which I think the object is not created/saved yet that is why there's no id yet. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

In any case, you should be able to achieve what you want using [PostGeneration](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#postgeneration)

```
class PlatformFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Platform
        exclude = ["user", ]

    @factory.post_generation
    def set_ext(obj, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            return
        obj.ext = f"{obj.user.key}|{obj.id}"
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Hi Rieljun, problem here is that the user is not part of the model itself (excluded) but I need the value for combining the key with the id. So now I get the message: AttributeError: 'Platform' object has no attribute 'user', but I shoul be able to use the factory insinde the set method.

Comment: ahh yeah, you're right, you need to use the user factory inside the set method.